# htaccess replace two occurs of dot in URL with only one

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to replace occurs of two dots in my image URL with only one dot

something like this

http://www.test.com/image..jpg

should be

http://www.test.com/image.jpg

I made this one but it seams that not working as I expect.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*)\..(jpe?g|gif|png)$ $1.$2 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Any help would be more than welcome.

Comment: It seems that my solution works on live server :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.\.(jpg|gif|bmp|jpeg|png)    $1.$2
```

Comment: Thanks, my solution works on remote server I had just local problem.